# function lqgtrack of python in matlab

Tags: python, matlab

Is there a way to see the source code of a Matlab function? I must implement the LQGTRack function of matlab in python. I must use it in a raspberry pi, therefore I can not use matlab directly

Comment: If the function is not a built-in one, you can see the source by typing `edit LQGTRack` (make sure you don't modify the file)

Comment: thank you very much friend. You saved me :)